# How to stop unwanted postback

Tags: asp.net

I work on ASP.NET C#. Under button click event I want to save something it's work fine, but after press the refresh button of browser, this event occurs again I want to stop this event.

Comment: @Jame: Always mark answer if the answer is helpful, you posted 18 question and not mark answer any of them.

Answer (score 8):

An article on this subject.

[Preventing Duplicate Record Insertion on Page Refresh](http://aspalliance.com/687)

***Approach 1***

> A simple solution is to
>   Response.Redirect back to the same
>   page after the INSERT command is
>   called.  This will call up the page
>   without transmitting any post headers
>   to it.  Using Request.Url.ToString()
>   as the first parameter of
>   Response.Redirect will cause both the
>   URL and the page's querystring to be
>   included in the redirect.  The use of
>   false as the second parameter will
>   suppress the automatic Response.End
>   that may otherwise generate a
>   ThreadAbortedException.  A
>   disadvantage of this approach is that
>   any ViewState that had been built up
>   will be lost.

***Approach 2***

A related approach would be for the form to submit to an intermediate processing page and then Response.Redirect back to the calling page, similar to the classic ASP approach to form processing.  This has the same effect as simply using the Response.Redirect in the Button_Click event so it has the same disadvantages, with the added disadvantage of creating another page for the website developer to manage.

***Approach 3***

> The next batch of solutions works by
>   determining whether the user has
>   refreshed the page in the browser
>   instead of pressing the form's submit
>   button.  All of these solutions depend
>   on the ability of the website to use
>   Session variables successfully.  If
>   the website uses cookie-based
>   Sessions, but the user's browser does
>   not permit the use of cookies, these
>   solutions would all fail. 
>   Additionally, should the Session
>   expire these solutions would also
>   fail.

***Approach 4***

> Should the user somehow manage to
>   circumvent the above mentioned solutions described
>   above, the last line of defense is at
>   the database.  There are two methods
>   that can be employed to prevent a
>   duplicate record from being inserted
>   into the database.  For each method,
>   I've moved the SQL code into a stored
>   procedure, since there are now more
>   processing steps involved and these
>   are easier to illustrate in a separate
>   stored procedure.  Note however that a
>   stored procedure is not strictly
>   required in order for these methods to
>   work.