# Reloading Page is giving rise to post data one more time (.NET issue)

Tags: .net, postback, reloading

I am trying to create something like shopping chart. The user adds products to his/her cart but if it click refresh button on the browser, the last product ,that is added before, is added one more time. How can I solve this problem ?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Very similar question here [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437273/how-to-stop-unwanted-postback](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437273/how-to-stop-unwanted-postback)

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [POST-Redirect-GET pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get).

Comment: Is there an ASP.NET mechanism to utilise this or does it require manual implementation?