# Webforms Refresh problem

Tags: c#, postback, webforms

This is probably a simple question for every WebForms developer but I am knew to this scene.  I have a page that has an "ADD" button on it that results in a jquery popup where the user can submit a form that will add an entry to the repeater on the page.  My problem is that after the user adds an item, if they then hit the refresh button the item will get added again.  I can't stop this with the page.ispostback because that would block the original add.  What can I do here?

Comment: Do you mean setting a bool in the original save, then passing it back and forth and checking it each time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that's a common problem. Here's explanation and solution of the problem.

When a web form is submitted to a server through an HTTP POST request, a web user that attempts to refresh the server response in certain user agents can cause the contents of the original HTTP POST request to be resubmitted, possibly causing undesired results, such as a duplicate web purchase.
To avoid this problem, many web developers use the PRG(Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

copied from wiki ([LINK](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get))

simplest solution can be [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt(v=vs.80).aspx) to the same page (i.e. if you page is named `default.aspx` write `Response.Redirect("default.aspx")`). if you do this browser refresh button will just load the page as if you have typed in address bar URL and navigated to it.

here's SO question [How to stop unwanted postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1437273/how-to-stop-unwanted-postback) that might be useful as well.

Answer (score 0):

If there is an option to delete an item on the page (is there?), do you really have to be concerned with that happening?  May want to think about that. Just a thought.